# How to customize access token with user information (user name, and phone number,..) in the oauth2.1 authorization server in the spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, openid, spring-boot-oauth2.1

How to customize access token with user information (user name, and phone number,..) in the oauth2.1 authorization server in the spring boot?

This my workaround [project](https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-authorization-server/), any resources/help on how to add user details in the access token itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add any information using `jwtCustomizer`. Refer [this](https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-authorization-server/blob/main/src/main/java/in/thirumal/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java)

```
    @Bean
    OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer(CustomClaims claims) {
        return context -> {
            if (context.getTokenType() == OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN) {
                Authentication principal = context.getPrincipal();
                Set<String> authorities = principal.getAuthorities().stream()
                        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
                context.getClaims().claims(c -> c.put("Creator", "Thirumal"));
                context.getClaims().claims(c -> c.putAll(claims.getClaims(principal)));
                context.getClaims().claim("roles", authorities);
            }
        };
    }
```